# if both shared and dynamic libraries are present, linker will prefer which library?

Tags: c++, linker, gnu

same options can be used for both statically linking and dynamically linking a library.
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -L$(PATH_TO_LIB) -l$(library name) -o output-file-name

If my PATH_TO_LIB contains both the .a and .so file, which one will linker prefer to?

Answer (score 1):

If the linker is a variant of ld then it will prefer shared objects over archives. From the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) of the `-l` flag, emphasis mine:

> -l *namespec*
>   --library=*namespec*
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of
>   files to link. This option may be used any number of times. If
>   namespec is of the form :*filename*, ld will search the library path
>   for a file called *filename*, otherwise it will search the library
>   path for a file called lib*namespec*.a.
>
> On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for
>   files other than lib*namespec*.a. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS
>   systems, **ld will search a directory for a library called
>   lib*namespec*.so before searching for one called lib*namespec*.a**.
>   (By convention, a .so extension indicates a shared library.) Note that
>   this behavior does not apply to :*filename*, which always specifies a
>   file called *filename*.